# How to specify PBKDF2 in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I want to use `PBKDF2` in web.config and I heard it is built into .NET.  I tried setting it like this:

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="false" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" hashAlgorithmType="PBKDF2" />
```

When I try this, I get the following error when trying to create a user:

`Unable to create new member The hash algorithm specified HMACSHA256 cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that will be possible.  See the GetHashAlgorithm method in Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs.

If the hashAlgorithmType contains "SHA" the provider returns a new HMACSHA1, otherwise you should use an algorithm named in this table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13(v=vs.110).aspx.